# Parameter to determine landing page - Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am very new to Magento, and trying to learn all Pros and Cons of my plans, as well as how to implement.

I am working with a client that has a well built out store.  With over hundreds of categories and subcategories.  I would like to modify this template a small amount(almost everything is CSS based), for landing pages only.  So for example visiting www.magentosite.com/category.html will display the page as it is now, but visiting www.magentosite.com/category.html?type=lp would display the same products with a slightly modified style.

This will be way easier then building out landing pages to match the already exiting categories.  Are there any magento cons to this?  If not, what file would be the best to add a few lines of php to get $_GET['type']?

Answer (score 1):

In the Backoffice :

- go to menu Catalog / Categories / Manage Categories
- select to category you want to customize
- go to the "Custom Design" Tab.

Here you can change de the design of your page for only this specific category .. (for example create a new specific .phtml template file .. or keep the same .phtml file but override it's css/js skin)

For more details, take a look here :

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_category/edit#custom_design_tab
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/customizing-category-page-design

**edit:**

If you need to customize a page based on its level (or on a GET parameter), you can use the Observer `catalog_controller_category_init_after`.

Inside it you can check its level (`$category->getLevel() == 1` ) or check a param in the Request (`Mage::app()->getRequest()->hasParam('type')`) in order to affect a new design
See Mage_Catalog_CategoryController::_initCatagory() for details on the Event parameters sended.
If you never used Observers, take a look at : http://codemagento.com/2011/04/observers-and-dispatching-events/

Comment: This is exactly what I would like to do VIA a parameter.  The pages are already setup and styled correctly, BUT I would like to alter the layout for landing pages.  So rather then creating duplicate pages for everything just for another layout, I would like to say if type == "lp" display new template, otherwise default.

Comment: i really don't understand why you want a get parameter , why not using standard magento functionnaly ? xplain yourself clearly please

Comment: I do want to use standard Magento functionality AS WELL AS a parameter.  This question is based around a landing page.  For example User A visits www.website.com and navigates his way to www.website.com/categorypage.  User B clicks a specific link from Google PPC for www.website.com/categorypage?type=lp.  The category and products are the same, but the layout and styling is different.  I have about 200 pages like this, so rather then rebuilding them all, this will be scalable for future as well.

Comment: OK then you should do this programatically using the LEVEL (system) attribute of the category. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thank you Bixi.  Like I said I am new to magento, so I really didn't know where to begin.  I have not userd Observers before, but at least now I have somewhere to start.

Comment: Yeah you'll get plenty of example over the net. don't hesitate to ask for some more help if needed.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is to create a cms page and the call the category block inside it.
You can call the category block by writing the following code in the WYSIWYG editor of the custom CMS page.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="respective-id-here" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

The link of the custom CMS Page will be 
www.magentosite.com/URL-Key.

You can get the category ID from the Admin Panel itself, by visiting the Catalog->Manage Category area.
You can then change the design by CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do what you're looking for is by using multiple store views and some htaccess rewrite rules. I am assuming you currently have a "Main Website", "Main Store Group", and "Default" store view.

First, add a new store view, you can name it whatever you want. Remember the "code" that you use because this will be needed in the next step. Let's assume the new store code is "custom".

Now, in the main .htaccess file add the following code that will set some environment variables based on a querystring parameter:

```
...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Set some environment variables based on the query string var "type"
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?])?type=lp(&.*|)$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:custom,E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:store]
</IfModule>
...
```

**Note:** The MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE environment variables are what's being set above. These are processed by Magento's index.php file which determines which Magento store view to use.

The last thing you need to do is configure your "custom" store view to use a different theme. You can do this in System > Configuration > Design, just make sure to change the configuration scope to your new custom view (the dropdown menu in the top left of the System > Configuration pages).

This may be over-kill for your current needs, but I use this tactic a lot when I want to add a quick way to change my Magento theme via the querystring.